# how do you address 'a' in unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

i have this div

```
<ul id = "issues">
<li>
<h1>titel</h1>
<p>tekst text tekst </p>
<a class="next" href="#">next</a>
</li>
<li>
<h1>titel</h1>
<p>tekst text tekst </p>
<a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a> 
</li>
....
</ul>
```

and this script

```
$('#issues li').each(       
        function(intIndex){

             $(this).nextAll('a').bind("click",function(){
             alert ('hello');

           });//close .bind()

        });//close .each
```

()

but it isn't working . how can i address the a-tag to see if someone clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#issues a').on('click',function(e){
  
  alert('you clicked '+this.className);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = "issues">
<li>
<h1>titel</h1>
<p>tekst text tekst </p>
<a class="next" href="#">next</a>
</li>
<li>
<h1>titel</h1>
<p>tekst text tekst </p>
<a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a> 
</li>
....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use correct selector's and you don't need `each()` for event binding.

```
$('#issues li a.next').click(function() {
    alert('Index of li: ' + $(this).closest('li').index());
});
```

Comment: this works, thanks, but how do you no the index of the 'li' ?

Comment: @MaggyLegrand, Use `$(this).closest('li').index()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over the elements to bind the event to them. use:

```
$('#issues .next').click(function(){
     alert ('hello');
});
```